# sed: joining lines depending on the fourth one

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that, occasionally, has split lines.

The split is signaled by the fact that two consecutive lines with Alphabetic characters.

```
5

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters

6

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters

7

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters

8

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters

.....
```

I'd like join the split line back:

```
5

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters

6

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters

7

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters

8

> 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters
.....
```

using sed. I'm not clear how to join a line with the preceeding one.
Any suggestion?

Comment: If it's a SRT file, then there's a blank line after the last text line (before the subtitle index), unlike your example.

Comment: can you [edit] your question because it does not reflect the actual format of a valid .SRT file. So solutions based on your example won't be satisfying.

Comment: You're right!
The correction has been made
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/[[:alpha:]]/{ if (buf=="") {buf=$0; next} else {$0=buf OFS $0; buf=""} } 1' file

5

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters

6

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000


7

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters

8

00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000

Alphabetic characters Alphabetic characters

.....
```

The above will work robustly, portably, and efficiently on all UNIX systems with all POSIX-compatible awks.

Comment: Thanks, works well for me.  
It's Possible, negation operator? 
like this --> "not equal to [:digit:]"

Comment: depending what you mean, that;s `!/[[:digit:]]/` or `/[^[:digit:]]/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '$!{N;/^[a-zA-Z ][^\n]\+\n[a-zA-Z ]/{s/\n/ /}}'
```

Match two lines back-to-back that meet the condition that the first line starts with an alphabetic character or space, and the second starts with the same.  Join them with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed '/^[[:alpha:]]/{N;/\n[[:alpha:]]/s/\n/ /}' file
```

When a line starting with alphabetic characters is found, add next line to the pattern space using the `N` command. Then replace newline when followed by alphabetic characters with a space.